# Imported Teradata date into SAS as Character (1/1/17)- how can i convert to SAS date9.?

Tags: date, sas, teradata

This is how I import from teradata:

```
libname DDWP_PLT teradata 
        user='xxxx'
        password='xxxx' 
        schema='DDWP_PLT_V' 
        server='phxtdpd2cop1.directv.com' 
        FASTEXPORT=YES; 

PROC SQL; 
    create table mob_base as 
    select ctn
         , ban
         , intrxn_id
         , sasdate
         , start_time
         , sessionstarttime
         , agent_ID
         , work_group as agent_skill
         , tasktype
         , taskresolution
         , need
         , need2
         , need3
         , disposition
         , note 
    from ddwp_plt.ATT_MOBILITY_CLARIFY_DTL_VW 
    where start_time between '2016-12-29 00:00:00' and '2017-01-31 23:59:59' 
    and start_time = sessionstarttime
    order by ctn
           , sessionstarttime 
    ;
QUIT;
```

Do I need to make it numeric first and then turn it into date?

I've tried:

```
format=date9.
INPUT(CATS(t1.column),BEST.)
Char = char X 1
```

these all resulted in no output

Comment: Please include example code showing how you're getting the Teradata data into SAS, and some details of how you connect to Teradata (is this using a libname, or a connect to..., or a defined connection handled by your sysadmin?)

Comment: this is how i import from teradata:libname DDWP_PLT teradata  
 user='xxxx'    
 password='xxxx'   
 schema='DDWP_PLT_V'    
 server='phxtdpd2cop1.directv.com'  
 
 FASTEXPORT=YES; 

PROC SQL;
create table mob_base as 
select ctn, ban,  intrxn_id, sasdate, start_time,
sessionstarttime, 
agent_ID, work_group as agent_skill, 
tasktype, taskresolution, need, need2, need3, disposition, note
from ddwp_plt.ATT_MOBILITY_CLARIFY_DTL_VW 
where start_time between '2016-12-29 00:00:00' and '2017-01-31 23:59:59' and start_time = sessionstarttime
order by ctn, sessionstarttime
;QUIT;

Comment: Is the current `start_time` field actually formatted as a date if you run a `proc contents` on it?

Comment: In sql environment you could use; select DATEPART(datevariable ,date).
In data step you can do:
data _delme; 
 begin=datetime();
 sas_date=datepart(begin);
 human_date=datepart(begin);
 format human_date yymmdd10.;
run;